# Is ISSET necessary if an array variable is already set?

Tags: php, arrays, isset

I have been learning about PHP variables and arrays and noticed that usually this kind of example is given:

```
<?php
    $foo = 1;
    if (isset($foo)) {
        echo "Foo is set\n";
    } else {
        echo "Foo is not set\n";
    }
?>
```

Now since $foo was already set to 1 at line 2, why bother checking that it's set with isset?

Surely it is sufficient to set a variable to a particular value:
eg. `$foo=1`, or `$myArray = [ ]`;

I understand the importance of initializing variables to make sure they don't contain unwanted values, and I can understand that in a situation where you have user input into a form, you may get empty fields and that needs to be checked, but in a situation where an array is filled **only** with data by the programmer (or already initialized), surely `isset` is not necessary.
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure a variable is set (like in the example given), there is no point in checking it. `isset` should be used for external input, such as input from a user filling out a form or a configuration file being read where you can't be sure the in advance that a variable gets set.

In this case the call to `isset` is useless, and is probably just shown for teaching purposes.

Answer (score 0):

No, It's not necessary.
The isset() function is used to check whether a variable is set or not. In this case, it will return true.

You could do if($foo), and it was going to return the same result.
Conditional statements in PHP return true if the value in variable ($foo in your case) was any other value than 0.

But if your variable had 0 and you was going to check it's set or not then it was going to return false but with `if(isset($foo))` will return true.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You should do `if ($foo)` only, when `$foo` contains a boolean value. Always check what you want to check, and not something that accidently elvaluates similar.

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` for above code is not useful since programmer knows the `$foo` is already set. Where as it is very useful when checking external variables or external inputs to global variables.

Suppose you have html form with one following submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="click">
```

Then you need to check the button clicked or not using `isset()`

```
isset($_POST["click"]){
     // code
}
```